# Finding tablename

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm

i've 8 tables.. assume it as x1,x2...x8.
these tables have similar structure with fields as: id,content,pageview.

Pageview count the number of views of particular id. post's are stored in rows with particular id's.

i want to find first top 10 post on the basis of pageview from these 8 tables.

i used :

```
$sql="select id,content from x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8 ORDER by pageview;"
```

results comes up.ok!
suppose results are like

Id    Content
13     this is just one
19     okay what to say
..
..
.

in this result i want to find this ID:19 belongs to which table?
I  can run loops to match content but that wont be fast enough  and good logic..

any solution to find tablename of particular id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample query will not run as is if you have the same field names in each table.  Not to mention that you're producing a cartesian product since you're not joining on any of your fields.

I think you might be looking for a `UNION` instead:

```
select *
from (
   select 'x1' as whichtable, id, content, pageview from x1
   union
   select 'x2' as whichtable, id, content, pageview from x2
   ...
   union
   select 'x8' as whichtable, id, content, pageview from x8
) t
order by pageview
```

Then you can use the whichtable field to see which table the result came from.

Here is a sample [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66cf3/2).

---

Just reread your post, and if you're looking for which table contains ID 19, then you can add a where clause to the above query:

```
select *
from (
   select 'x1' as whichtable, id, content, pageview from x1
   union
   select 'x2' as whichtable, id, content, pageview from x2
   ...
   union
   select 'x8' as whichtable, id, content, pageview from x8
) t
where id = 19
order by pageview
```